# Document and bibliography in different languages with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, spanish

I'm writing my thesis in Spanish. However, I'd like that the bibliography is in English with biblatex. My document is like this:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%BIBLIOGRAPHY
\usepackage[style=numeric,url=false,issn=false,maxbibnames=99,backend=biber,sorting=none]{biblatex}%<- specify style
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{%
  andothers = {\textit{et al}\adddot}
  }
\addbibresource{references.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document} 
\printbibliography[title={Bibliografía}]
\end{document}
```

For example, one bibitem is:

```
@ARTICLE{Scoup1,
 author         = "Dolan, Matthew J. and Englert, Christoph and Spannowsky,
                        Michael",
      title          = "{Higgs self-coupling measurements at the LHC}",
      journal        = "JHEP",
      volume         = "10",
      year           = "2012",
      pages          = "112",
      doi            = "10.1007/JHEP10(2012)112",
      eprint         = "1206.5001",
      archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
      primaryClass   = "hep-ph",
      reportNumber   = "IPPP-12-43, DCPT-12-86",
      SLACcitation   = "%%CITATION = ARXIV:1206.5001;%%"
}
```

And it appears like this in the document:

Matthew J. Dolan, Christoph Englert **y** Michael Spannowsky. “Higgs self-coupling measurements at the LHC”.JHEP10 (2012), **pág.** 112. DOI:10.1007/JHEP10(2012)112. arXiv:1206.5001[hep-ph].

like I said, in Spanish. What I want is this:

Matthew J. Dolan, Christoph Englert **and** Michael Spannowsky. “Higgs self-coupling measurements at the LHC”.JHEP10 (2012), **page** 112. DOI:10.1007/JHEP10(2012)112. arXiv:1206.5001[hep-ph].

To sum up, I'd like English bibliography in Spanish document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the language directly as an option for `biblatex` with `language=english`. But you have to take care of a couple of other things for that to work. You must include `english` to the list of languages for `babel` (before `spanish`, for the last listed language is the default, and your document is in Spanish). And you must also instruct `biblatex` to enclose your references in an `otherlanguage` environment, which can be done with `autolang=other`.

Putting things together:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%BIBLIOGRAPHY
\usepackage[style=numeric,url=false,isbn=false,maxbibnames=99,backend=biber,sorting=none,language=english,autolang=other]{biblatex}%<- specify style
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{%
  andothers = {\textit{et al}\adddot}
}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Scoup1,
 author         = "Dolan, Matthew J. and Englert, Christoph and Spannowsky,
                        Michael",
      title          = "{Higgs self-coupling measurements at the LHC}",
      journal        = "JHEP",
      volume         = "10",
      year           = "2012",
      pages          = "112",
      doi            = "10.1007/JHEP10(2012)112",
      eprint         = "1206.5001",
      archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
      primaryClass   = "hep-ph",
      reportNumber   = "IPPP-12-43, DCPT-12-86",
      SLACcitation   = "%%CITATION = ARXIV:1206.5001;%%"
} 
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={Bibliografía}]
\end{document}
```

Which renders:

[image]

Comment: Wow, so simple. Thank you very much that has been very useful