# How to choose a LaTeX bibliography language

Tags: bibliographies, babel

I'm writing a article in Brazilian Portuguese but the bibliography is coming out in English. I'll show what I mean.

I'm using a .bib document for the citations entries, the following packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.0cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2cm, right=1cm, top=1cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

and :

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{referencias}
```

For the bibliography.

Finally, the problem is that the entry types that uses a field that display a preposition displays it in English. Example:

```
@book{book,
    author      =   {autor},
    title       =   {título},
    volume      =   {X},
    series      =   {serie},
    publisher   =   {editora},
    year        =   {ano},
    }
```

Will result in "autor, título, **of** serie, editora, ano".

I need the word **of** to be in Brazilian Portuguese.

Comment: I think `\DefineBibliographyStrings{<lang>}{<strings>}` might help you. See, for instance, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430198/document-and-bibliography-in-different-languages-with-biblatex).

Comment: @ÓscarGuajardo That is a `biblatex` macro, and Lucas is using the base bibliography methods, so this will not work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se! The code you've posted does not produce an 'of' in the references at all, so you must be doing something else. Is `biblatex` an option for you? It's probably a better choice, in which case @ÓscarGuajardo 's suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: @AlanMunn Sorry, I just edited it so the "of" will show as in my document.
I don't know if biblatex is an option for me, it probably is but I have yet to learn how to use it.

Comment: The basic `unsrt` and `unsrtnat` (the `natbib` version of `unsrt`) have these strings hard coded into the `.bst` file, and are not aware of `babel`. You could make a Portuguese version of them, but it might be more sensible to switch to `biblatex`, which has much better language support out of the box.  Using `\usepackage[style=numeric-comp, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{referencias.bib}` in the preamble and then `\printbibliography` in the text will produce most of what you need, although this style has no 'of' at all.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll have to learn how to use biblatex.
Thanks Óscar Guajardo and Alan Munn for your help.

Comment: Probably start here: [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509) and here [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751)